# How to display only property that has a match in array of objects? Typeahead

Tags: angularjs, typeahead.js, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

Hi I have an array of objects that I want to filter using typeahead.

this is my input tag

```
<input type="text" ng-change="onedit()"  ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state as state.city for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
```

This is the array I want to filter:

```
$scope.states = [
      {state: 'Alabama', firstName: "Jim"},
      {state: 'Alaska', firstName: "Tom"},
      {state: 'Arizona', firstName: "Alan"},
      {state: 'Arkansas', firstName: "Mark"},
      {state: 'California', firstName: "Maria"}
]
```

At the moment it displays only the state whether it matches the firstName or state. How can I make that it will display only firstName properties if it matches firstName and to display only states if it matches states

Here is my [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/0AWpwdSeagineE9wRPbe?p=preview)

The typeahead I am using I think is from angular-bootstrap.

I am pretty sure you can do that as I saw it in some online example but cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

Be specific with `firstName` property while applying `filter`.

```
uib-typeahead="state as state.city for state in states 
               | filter: { firstName: $viewValue} | limitTo:8">
```

[**Forked Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CYtS31Puf1dMiPTUXbVs?p=preview)

Comment: it does the same thing. nothing changed. I just checkedthe plunker. and I think here you restricted to filter only by firstName. what I need is to find a match in both state or name, but let's say it found Alan, then display only firstName match, if it has a match in state display state value that matches. E.g. I type "AL" and get a list of "ALan, ALaska, ALabama". Now if I have in 1 object {state: Alaska, firstName: Alan} and want to type  "Alan"  I get the state name displayed instead of firstName

Comment: `state as (state.state + ' ' + state.firstName)` could be what you want? It highlights either state or firstName...

Comment: @Ric I need them separate in case you want to find by first name, last name or email or city. imagine you type email but instead you get the full name. I want to see the suggestions as you type. For example I need to see the email of a user, and I know only user name, so when I insert "john" I want to see something like johndoe@mail.com.   The annoying thing is that I saw it before working somewhere but can't find it anymore :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread question. Tell me what if you have `searchQuery` matches with `firstName` of one record and `lastName` of other. What you wanted to see in result? Only results with firstName / lastName